# Accessing an element in an Array if that Array is inside an Arraylist.

Tags: java, arrays

If I wanted to access an element inside an array, I would use this expression: array[index]. If I wanted to access an element inside an array inside an array, I would use this expression: array[index][index]. My problem is, how do I access an element in an array if that array is inside an arraylist? I have to use the .get method to access elements inside an arraylist. Doing something like arraylist.get(index) only returns the array, and I can't access any elements inside that array. Please help!

Comment: `arrayList.get(x)[y]`?

Comment: `arraylist.get(index)[index]`?

Comment: Thank you, I guess my head wasn't working. haha

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Use **parens** (calling a method) combined with **square-brackets** (accessing the array).

```
myList.get(…)[…]
```

## Details

Define your `ArrayList` as containing an array. In this case, an array of `String` objects.

```
List < String[] > list = new ArrayList <>( 2 );
```

Populate.

```
String[] a1 = { "alpha" , "beta" , "gamma" };
String[] a2 = { "Bill Bixby" , "Lana Lang" , "Wendy Melvoin" , "Lisa Coleman" };

list.add( a1 );
list.add( a2 );
```

Retrieve your array from the `List` by calling `get`. Note that `get` uses annoying zero-based counting is used both by `List::get` and by the array. So the second element is `1`.

```
String ll = list.get( 1 )[ 1 ]; // Zero-based counting on both the list and the array.

System.out.println( ll );
```

> Lana Lang

The longer version of that code would be this.

```
String[] array = list.get( 1 ) ;  // Return the 2nd element’s array.
String ll = array[ 1 ];           // Access the 2nd element in the array, a String object.
```

Tip: Generally speaking, you may be better off **just using collections** rather than arrays. Nothing wrong with arrays, but they are simplistic. Collections offer many other features. While arrays are faster and use less memory, neither is a significant consideration for most business-oriented app scenarios.

Tip: You may find handy the new `List.of` methods added in Java 9 and later. If you were using arrays for their easy literals syntax, `List.of`, `List.copyOf` (in Java 10), & `Map.of` may do the trick now.